# Warning in visual studio in simple sfinae code

Tags: c++, c++11

I am writing a simple code for learning sfinae. However, it generates a warning only in Visual Studio (not when using g++).

The code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <class T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, nullptr_t>::type = nullptr>
void f(T t)
{
    std::cout << "Integer" << std::endl;
    return;
}

template <class T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_integral<T>::value, nullptr_t>::type = nullptr>
void f(T t)
{
    std::cout << "not integer" << std::endl;
    return;
}


int main()
{
    f(10);
    f(5.5);
    f("Hello");

    return 0;
}
```

And the warning is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\ostream(746): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
sfinae2.cpp(9): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,const char *)' being compiled
sfinae2.cpp(23): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void f<int,nullptr>(T)' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=int
        ]
```

The warning disappears when compiling with the flag `/EHsc`, or when deleting the `cout` from both functions.

I want to know why this flag is needed.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know why this flag is needed.

From [msvc's exception handling model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/eh-exception-handling-model?view=msvc-170):

> ##### Arguments
>
> `c`
>
> When used with `/EHs`, the **compiler assumes that functions declared as** `extern "C"` **never throw a C++ exception**. It has no effect when used with /EHa (that is, /EHca is equivalent to /EHa). /EHc is ignored if /EHs or /EHa aren't specified.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Ok, I now understand the cause of this warning: the c++ standard indicates that throwing exceptions from extern "C" code is undefined behavior, but this behavior can be configured in visual studio. However, it seems strange to me that warnings are generated with a simple c++ code when not using the flag.